# CFTs of Integrable models XXX, XXZ, Hubbard

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, integrable-systems

I want to know if someone knows the answer to the following question (or can explain to me why the question makes no sense):

Consider the standard integrable models, like the XXX-Chain, the XXZ-Chain, or the Hubbard-Model, what are the CFTs describing the low energy physics in the thermodynamic limit? Is this question already answered or still open? If the former case is true, I would appreciate literature for the explicit construction of the CFTs.

Comment: Yes, the identification of the CFTs relevant to those models is well-understood. See for example Chapters 5 and especially 7 of Eduardo Fradkin's book *Field Theories of Condensed Matter Physics*.